Minimal permissions required to Deploy a custom MS teams app to a tenant
I am using Teams Toolkit in Visual studio Code to Provision, Deploy and Publish my custom MS Teams app to a tenant.
My question is: What are the minimal permissions/user role required to be able to execute the DEPLOY action - the one that uploads the app code to Azure? (for Provision I think you need a Global administrator role, and Publish I think it needs the Teams Administrator role).

No one has no clue about this, please?
